# Vector-based flood-fill algorithm queue class

Tags: java

I want to implement the flood-fill algorithm for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12995378/is-there-a-proper-algorithm-for-detecting-the-background-color-of-a-figure. I did it recursively, but I had a stack-overflow error. No matter - Wikipedia has a spot for a non-recursive, iterative solution.

It requires a queue. For school, we're not supposed to use Lists nor the Java Queue class (I don't even know if it does what I think it does, but it doesn't matter - I can't use it).

```
public class QueueOfPixeles
{
    public Pixel[] elements;
    public int numberOfElements;

    public QueueOfPixeles()
    {
        numberOfElements = 0;
        elements = new Pixel[1];
    }

    // Next pixel is supposed to return the last pixel element in the queue.
    // When a pixel element is returned, it will become null in the system.
    public Pixel nextPixel() {
        Pixel result = null;
        for (int i = elements.length - 1; i >= 0 && result == null; --i) {
            result = elements[i];
            if (result != null) {
                elements[i] = null;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    // Adds a new pixel to the queue.
    // Then, it checks if the capacity of the vector has been reached.
    public void add(Pixel pixel) {
        elements[numberOfElements] = pixel;
        ++numberOfElements;
        fixVector();
    }

    // If the vector capacity has been reached, create a new vector with all old elements
    // but with more capacity.
    private void fixVector() {
        if (numberOfElements >= elements.length) {
            Pixel[] newVector = new Pixel[(elements.length * 2) + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; ++i) {
                newVector[i] = elements[i];
            }
            elements = newVector;
        }
    }
}
```

**WHAT IS IT SUPPOSED TO DO?**

You should be able to add pixels to the end of the queue, and get the next pixel by using `nextPixel()`. When you retrieve the next pixel, it should be removed from the queue automatically.

**DOES IT WORK?**

Yes, it seems to be working. I've done a few tests and it has indeed returned all I expected.

**WHAT'S THE PROBLEM?**

I'd like to get some feedback about this. I can only use vectors for this project, and I feel there is something rather not-efficient with the way I manage the pixels in the queue (converting the elements to null and just that etc, or asking for more capacity size instead of using the null-spaces I made).

What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A note on terminology: What you have implemented is usually called a *stack* rather than a queue, but it can also be called a LIFO (last in, first out) queue, so it's not wrong to call it a queue, only uncommon.

The `nextPixel()` method is rather inefficient. You keep track of the number of elements in the queue, and you never do anything that allows any array element with an index `>= numberOfElements` to be anything but `null`. So instead of starting the search at `elements.length - 1`, you should start at `numberOfElements - 1`.

But that still leaves an inconsistency/inefficiency. The `add()` method doesn't guard against adding `null`s to the queue, but you never return a `null` until the queue is empty.

You should either return `null`s if you accept them to be added to the queue, or, better, I think, guard against `null`s in `add()`. So I'd recommend

```
public void add(Pixel pixel) {
    if (pixel == null) return; // nothing to do
    // pixel isn't null, add it
    elements[numberOfElements] = pixel;
    ++numberOfElements;
    fixVector();
}
```

and then - also if you decide to return `null`s if they're added - `nextPixel()` can simply be

```
public Pixel nextPixel() {
    // queue empty
    if (numberOfElements == 0) return null;
    // decrement numberOfElements and
    // return the last added Pixel
    return elements[--numberOfElements];
}
```

In `fixVector()`, you can probably be a bit more efficient if you use the generic `Arrays.copyOf` method, but maybe you are not allowed to use that either.

Comment: You can also write ` elements[numberOfElements++] = pixel; ` and remove the next line

Comment: Note: Wow, the changes made my program like 20 times faster! Now I can handle big images :D. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel Fisher already mentioned, you're using a Stack. The most basic implementation of this is a single linked list. The down side is that it consumes more memory than an array based implementation. The up side is that it is **much** easier to implement: You don't have to juggle with indexes, you don't have to copy the array content etc.